# Cannot search for sites in Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I try to query a team in MS Teams by name or displayName.
`search` and `filter` both don't seem to work:
(currently using HttpClient GET-requests)

First of all, I can query all sites
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites`

and $select works fine like this
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$select=sharepointIds,name,displayname`

But these all fail:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$search="displayName:IT-Team"`
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$search=(displayName eq "IT-Team")`
=empty result (also for other attempts with 'name')
(BadRequest when using `'`)

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$filter=startsWith(name,'IT')`
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$filter=displayName eq 'IT-Team'`
= BadRequest (it works for users and groups)

The empty result looks like this:
`{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites","value":[]}`

"search" should work for sites:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

How do I get sites by name/displayName?
I don't want to query *all* sites just to get a SiteId.

Comment: The tile mentions Teams, however all your examples and questions are regarding Sharepoint Sites. Can you clarify what your are actually asking ? Teams or SharePoint ?

Comment: @JosVerlinde, I am working with Microsoft Teams and try to query information about the 'teams' in Teams. The query for a team is "/sites/", as far as I can see.

Comment: @JosVerlinde is right. As far as I know, `sites` refers to SharePoint sites. I don't know much about Teams, but I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: It may be that the Teams-part is not relevant here. I DO find all my teams under /sites/ and I need the siteId for further queries.

Comment: The storage behind Microsoft teams is SharePoint, so the two are definitely linked.
The sharepoint site queries need some getting used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search="IT-Team"` searches the `displayName` and `description` fields of `site` resources for the search term and returns matching sites. I realize that this is not exactly, what you are looking for (you want to find sites, where `displayName` equals your search term), but it might still be helpful to you or others.

Comment: That sounds helpful, I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: This is okay for me, although there are some differences: does not include the `sharepointIds` by default (but can be added via `$select`). And apparently the `name`-property is different (spaces removed, but included when querying all `.../sites`)

Comment: you need to craft a SharePoint Site query 
for more details : 
 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-beta#sharepoint-api-root-resources
 - https://collab365.com/use-rest-api-microsoft-graph-query-sharepoint-sites/